# Adding a string at the end of each line where string is present

Tags: bash, shell

I want to add in each line in file a string where each line contain a value in special list of pattern.

1- I save the output of the file in var that :

var5=$(cat information.txt)

```
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151114201|PF15_ZZZZ-D|05|NVBOR701
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151111164|PF95_TESV-D|05|NVBAY701
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0159321163|PF15_ZZZZ-D|05|NVBOR701
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151112626|PF95_AWAW-D|05|NVBAY701
```

2- My list of pattern are :

```
list_of_pattern="0151114201
0151112626"
```

3- my string that i want to added in the end of each line is :

```
string="|R12"
```

i try this but no result :

```
[[ "$var5" =~ $list_of_pattern ]] && var5+=$string
echo "$var5"
```

I want this output:

```
 OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151114201|PF15_ZZZZ-D|05|NVBOR701|R12
 OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151111164|PF95_TESV-D|05|NVBAY701
 OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0159321163|PF15_ZZZZ-D|05|NVBOR701
 OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151112626|PF95_AWAW-D|05|NVBAY701|R12
```

Please help

Comment: Is the list of patterns also stored in some file? Or only in a variable?

Comment: in a variable not in the same file

Comment: `[[ "$var5" =~ $list_of_pattern ]]` requires that `list_of_patterns` be a regex that matches your patterns, not (as it apparently is) a multi-line string with one pattern per line.

Comment: ...is there a reason you're dumping your whole file into a variable, rather than reading into a variable one line at a time?

Comment: Also, don't tag tools you think someone *might* use in an answer. Tagging is for tools (languages, &c) a question is actually *about*.

Comment: (Added `bash` because `[[ $string =~ $re ]]` syntax is an extension, so doesn't make sense with only a generic `shell` tag).

Comment: Where does the list of patterns come from originally? Is it fixed, or does it come from the output of a command, or a file, or what?

Comment: Tom Fenech, it's a fix pattern

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you used a text processing tool, such as awk.

If you can pass the patterns to awk one at a time, then your script could be something like this:

```
awk -F'|' -v p1="0151114201" -v p2="0151112626" '$5 == p1 || $5 == p2 { 
    $0 = $0 FS "R12"
} 1' file
```

If the fifth field contains one of the patterns, then add another field containing `R12` to the end of the line. `1` at the end means everything always gets printed.

If you want to match one of the patterns anywhere in the line, then change `$5 ==` (fifth field is equal to) to `$0 ~` (line matches the regex).

---

If you actually have more than two strings that you would like to match, you could read them into an array before processing the file like this:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR == FNR { s[$0]; next } # set keys for each line in the first input
$5 in s { $0 = $0 FS "R12" } 1' patterns file
```

This assumes that the strings to match are in a file called `patterns`, but you can also use a process substitution if you want, changing `patterns` to `<(command_to_produce_patterns)` (which in your example could be `<(echo "$list_of_pattern")`).

Comment: If the list of patterns is longer, you can simplify it by passing the complete list via process substitution as the first file, something like: `awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{pat[$0];next} ($5 in pat){$0=$0"|R12"}1' <(echo "$list_of_pattern") information.txt`

Comment: @randomir yeah you're right, I added something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your `list_of_patterns` needs to be a regex to be used on the right-hand side of `=~`. Thus, the following properly emits your stated output:

```
pattern='([|]|^)(0151114201|0151112626)([|]|$)'
string="|R12"

while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $pattern ]] && line+='|R12'
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done <<EOF
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151114201|PF15_ZZZZ-D|05|NVBOR701
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151111164|PF95_TESV-D|05|NVBAY701
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0159321163|PF15_ZZZZ-D|05|NVBOR701
OK|2017-11-03|10:00:00.000|03-NOV-17|0151112626|PF95_AWAW-D|05|NVBAY701
EOF
```